# Abstract definition of a vector space

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Can one define a vector space over a field F as a tensor product of an abelian group (as Z module) with F?

Comment: Give reasoning that why are you thinking so? Usually explain how do you find the inverse of integers.

Comment: It is true that every vector space linearly isomorphic to one such vector space. However, I would guess that the realtionship between $M$ and $k\otimes_{\Bbb Z} M$ is not easily handled. For instance, the map $M\to k\otimes_{\Bbb Z} M$, $m\mapsto 1\otimes m$ is not injective: specifically, its $\ker$ contains all the elements of $m$ such that $(0:m)\ne(\operatorname{char}k)$. Also, you may have funny stuff such as $\dim_{\Bbb R}\left(\Bbb R\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\left(\Bbb R\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z\right)\right)=\beth_1$, whereas $\dim_{\Bbb R}(\Bbb R\otimes_{\Bbb Z}\Bbb Z)=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite, but you have a good idea! What is true is that, for any $\mathbb{Z}$-module $A$, $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F$ has a natural $F$-vector space structure. Moreover, for any $F$-vector space $V$, there is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $A$ such that $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F \cong V$. However, the concept of an $F$-vector space is *not* the same as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module tensored with $F$. You can tell that this is literally true because ${-} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F$ is not an equivalence of the categories in question (more on this later), but I'll try to answer the potential followup question of "why isn't this the definition of vector space instead?"

One reason is that we want to have $F$-vector spaces which are not literally equal to $A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F$ (otherwise, most statements and constructions in linear algebra become extremely tedious, e.g. what does "linearly independent" mean and how do you define the vector space structure on hom-sets? We can certainly answer these questions if we know what an $F$-action is, but then we've already defined vector spaces as normal). It's also much too restrictive in the sense that we only allow ourselves the natural $F$-action to work with on each tensor product.

Another reason is that this definition produces the same vector space in many different ways. To be more precise, what you've really described is a functor $A \mapsto A \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F : \mathbb{Z}\,\mathsf{Mod} \to F\,\mathsf{Mod}$ from the category of abelian groups to the category of $F$-vector spaces. This functor is always essentially surjective (as described earlier) but is never fully faithful. For example, if $F$ has characteristic $0$, then $T \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} F = 0$ for any torsion abelian group $T$. This means we have no hope of *uniquely* (up to isomorphism) representing $F$-vector spaces as tensor products in this way.

A vector space is truly the data of an abelian group with an $F$-action, and as such the only "good" definition is "a ring homomorphism $F \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A)$ for some abelian group $A$", or something equivalent to that.

Hope this was somewhat helpful! Happy to expand more on these ideas if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful! The question was triggered while watching Jacob Lurie‘s lecture https://youtu.be/LeaiPHAh0X0 where he defines a Lie algebra on the basis of an abelian group only. No mentioning of a field or even a ring. So just on a Z module...